# two association belongs_to with the same models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I have two classes : User, Patent and Help (belongs_to :user and belongs_to :patent)
When I click to a link I must create an "Help" that refer to the patent and also to the users. One user is the helper and the other one is the caller.

patents_controller:

```
def create        
    @patent = Patent.find(params[:patent_id])
    @patent.helps.create(:caller_id => @current_user.id, :user => @patent.user)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @patent }
      format.js
  end
end
```

The problem is I created a "caller_id" to store the second user.id that is not liked to the user model.
`<%= help.user.name %>` give me the right name of the first
how can I show the name of the caller from his `caller_id` or make some connection ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell the relation that the caller is a user. So..

```
belongs_to :caller, :class_name => 'user'
```